# CLEditor - getting dynamic ID of textarea field

Tags: jquery, cleditor

I have multiple textarea rows. If a user makes changes to any of the field then that should be updated using an ajax call.

Issue: I can't seem to get the id of the dynamic textarea field. I need to parse the id to insert the data in the ajax call for that row id.

```
//jquery
    $('textarea[id^=notetext_]').cleditor().change(function (){
            alert($(this).attr('id'));
    }); 



//html part    
<textarea name=notetext[] id=notetext_". $row["rowid"]." class='notetext'>".$row["notetext"]."</textarea>
```

This gives me "undefined". I can use .each function but then the ajax call will update all the fields whether they are changed or not. It slows down the edit process as it has to update all the fields.

Comment: are you talking about CKEditor?

Comment: @xploshioOn No, CLEditor